# Use of Add Type and Formula1 in Data Validation VBA: Error 1004

Tags: vba, validation

I know this question has been covered before and I've tried looking through all the answers, but I am still getting the below error

`1004 error: Application-defined or object-defined error.`

Below is the code:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("A10").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=Join(DPHeight, ",")
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True    
End With
```

`DPHeight` is a dynamic array that has been generated previously.
The code stops on the

`.Add` line

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What is `DPHeight`?

Comment: DPHeight is a dynamic array that has been generated previously

Comment: :) Cool. What is in this dynamic array?

Comment: a list of numbers

Comment: We are going there. Can you give an example. E.g. `DPHeight = Array(12,3,41)`?

Comment: + How do you define the dynamic array?

Comment: Dim DPHeight () As String

Comment: DPHeight = Array("34", "46", "67") would be an example. Although they're numbers I need to process them as strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open a new Excel file.
- Write this:

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub TetMe()

    Dim DPHeight    As Variant
    DPHeight = Array("34", "46", "67")

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A10").Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=Join(DPHeight, ",")
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Then check the value of A10. The should be a data validation list present.

Comment: I've changed the declaration to

Comment: @KevWilliams - give it a try. The important part is to check whether the cell has a validation, before inserting a new one.

Comment: Now I get an error '13' Type mismatch. Everything else is the same as the example

Comment: Start from the beginning, with a new Excel and it will work, @KevWilliams